# Sending fpdf attachments does not work on my linux suse server but it does on my shared hosting account

Tags: linux, email, attachment, vps, fpdf

I have a php program i have developed on the internet. So far i have used a shared hosting package. Everything worked until i moved to a vps (apache2 suse 9.1 plesk) . I have found certain php functions have not been activated. I have solved most of them by using the internet.

My main problem is emailing pdfs with fpdf. i.e

```
<?php
// download fpdf class (http://fpdf.org)
require("fpdf.php");

// fpdf object
$pdf = new FPDF();

// generate a simple PDF (for more info, see http://fpdf.org/en/tutorial/)
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",14);
$pdf->Cell(40,10, "this is a pdf example");

// email stuff (change data below)
$to = "steven@siteaddress.co.uk"; 
$from = "me@domain.com"; 
$subject = "send email with pdf attachment"; 
$message = "<p>Please see the attachment.</p>";

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "example.pdf";

// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));


// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;

// message
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;

// attachment
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
$headers .= "--".$separator."--";

// send message
//mail($to, $subject, "", $headers);
if (@mail($to, $subject, "",$headers)) {  
 echo('<p>Mail sent successfully.</p>');  
} else {  
 echo('<p>Mail could not be sent.</p>');  
}  

?>
```

The file above works on my share hosting , but when it comes to sending from my vps i get this error message from my file

```
Mar 23 19:16:56 h1871885 suhosin[64630]: ALERT - mail() - double newline in headers, possible injection, mail dropped (attacker '86.137.40.199', file '/srv/www/vhosts/sitename.co.uk/httpdocs/main/email.php', line 111)
```

after much trial, the error is from this line

```
 if (@mail($to, $subject, "",$headers))
```

If i remove the "", it sends the email on my vps but there is no attachment. this also happens on my shared account. The attachment ends up in the message with a hole load of chars'. 
So i def need them in there. does anyone have a clue how to overcome this problem.

many thanks

after setting suhosin.ini to 0

```
Mar 23 20:52:48 h1871885 suhosin[60778]: ALERT - mail() - double newline in headers, possible injection, mail dropped (attacker '86.137.40.199', file '/srv/www/vhosts/sitename.co.uk/httpdocs/main/email1.php', line 56)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an awful lot of `.$eol.$eol` in your `$headers`, and I imagine suhosin is forbidding the mail on the second instance. But I presume you've looked enough at [RFC2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) to know exactly where you need blank lines in your message formatting, so you can [turn off suhosin's `mail()` protection](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.mail.protect), assuming you're confident that you don't have any remotely exploitable injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Steve Kinnear, you can configure suhosin in your `php.ini` file, try looking in `/etc/php/php.ini` to see if I guessed the pathname correctly.

Comment: I have changed the sushosin.ini file. suhosin.mail.protect = 0 but with still no luck. any other ideas sarnold

Comment: @STeven Kinnear, you probably need to either reload Apache's configs or reload FastCGI's configs, to make sure suhosin reloads its configuration file. If you've already reloaded the configs, what error message are you getting now?

Comment: updated first post with error. To reload apache's config i just rebooted the server. Is that enough?

Comment: Hehehe, more than enough. :) Normally `/etc/init.d/ap<tab> reload` would do the job. :) But I don't know why you're still getting that message -- try disabling suhosin completely?

Comment: I renamed the file, rebooted and this time the file sends but no attachment. its like removing the "" from the first post. I might look at anotherway of creating the attachment i found a link here http://www.astahost.com/info.php/create-email-pdf-file-fly-php_t6334.html hopefully this will help. thanks sarnold for your input

Comment: Sarnold. It works. Dont ask me why or how. but when i put the old sushin.ini file back in the attachment now sends. ;)

Comment: @Steven Kinnear, heh, I _hate_ those things, when they just start to work and you're left wondering what exactly fixed it...